# Why Qt can't see its own header files?

Tags: c++, qt

Usually when I includes Qt standard headers I just used, for example, `#include <QImage>`. But now I need to add before it a part of path to Qt file location, like that: `#include <qt5/QtGui/QImage>`. Earlier Qt identified its location by itself. I tried to add to `.pro` file `INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5`, but it doesn't work. In `QTDIR` enviroment variable the same path is assigned.

I've included `gui` component in `.pro` file.

What's problem?

Answer (score 0):

Keep your include path as:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5
```

But reference the header includes like this:

```
#include <QtGui/QImage>
```

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work too :(

Comment: Show the output to your build and validate that you have a QtQui/QImage file underneath your `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5` folder

Comment: I have QtGui/QImage file in the directory. 
As for the first question... Thing is that compiler doesn't show anything about it. Only QtCreator emphasizes the include line and says: "No such file or directory". 
Usually, the program builds and runs without any errors, but, firstly, it's uncomfortable, secondly, sometimes it leads to errors, when some header files can't be found